# Why does this DateTime subtraction operation return invalid results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two DateTime objects, one in the past and one representing the current datetime. I am trying to find out how many minutes have passed between the two:

```
past = "Wed, 03 Jul 2013 00:59:39 UTC +00:00".to_datetime
now  = "Wed, 03 Jul 2013 01:04:19 +0100".to_datetime

seconds = (now - past)             #result is (-83/2160)
```

This is incorrect. Seconds should be 280, the number of seconds that have passed between the two times.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting two DateTimes returns the elapsed time in days.

So you can do:

```
past = "Wed, 03 Jul 2013 00:59:39 UTC +00:00".to_datetime
now  = "Wed, 03 Jul 2013 01:04:19 +0100".to_datetime
seconds = (now - past) * 1.day
# => -3320.0
```

Or you could do:

```
seconds = (now.to_i - past.to_i)
# => -3320
```

※ The result is negative because of the Timezone.

```
past.utc
# => Wed, 03 Jul 2013 00:59:39 +0000 
now.utc
# => Wed, 03 Jul 2013 00:04:19 +0000
```

You can see that `now` is actually older than `past`.

Comment: thanks for this, I am getting -3320 when I run the above code - is anyone else getting that?

Comment: @Jason where do you get this? What is the code you are using?

Comment: I run the code in your example, line by line. I am using ruby 1.9.3p429

Comment: @Jason -3320 is the right answer! I'm sorry I was making my test in ruby 1.8 and it did not take the timezone in account while ruby 1.9 does. I edited my answer.